# Loading external php into tooltip div

Tags: php, css, tooltip

I have a tooltip with a simple contact form that I want to load the "message sent" int to the same tooltip div instead of loading a external submit.php page.

```
<div id="contactform" >        
            <form method="post" action="submit.php">
            <label for="Name">name</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="Name" id="name" /><br />

            <label for="Email">email</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="Email" id="email" /><br />

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send" class="submit" id="submit"/>
            </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: That will require an AJAX request. Start reading around here for myriad examples to get started. JavaScript libraries like jQuery simplify the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `header`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#contactform form').submit(function()
    {
        var dataString=$(this).serialize();

        $.post('/ajax/submit.php', dataString, function(txt)
        {
            $('#contactform').html(txt);
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

**[jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)**

**PHP (/ajax/submit.php)**

```
<?php

if($_POST['submit'] == 'send')
{
    /* your PHP code */

    echo 'Your message was sent.';
}

?>
```

Comment: thank you, now all the acctiaon is taking place inside my tooltip div so that is perfect, but instead of showing the message i just get a blank div. I supose there is something rotten in my php but can't figure out what..

Comment: $EmailFrom = "XXX";
$EmailTo = "mymail@mymail.com";
$Subject = "Subject";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
exit;}
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Mail: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: $EmailFrom");
echo 'Your message was sent.';
}?>

Comment: Try to remove the `}` add the end.

Comment: BTW, I'd probably write `if(!$validationOK){echo 'Sorry, something went wrong. Please try it again.';}else{echo 'Your message was successfully sent.';}` instead.

Comment: <?php
if($_POST['submit'] == 'send')
{
$EmailFrom = "XXX";
$EmailTo = "mymail@mymail.com";
$Subject = "Subject";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Mail: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n"; 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: $EmailFrom");
}
$validationOK=true;if(!$validationOK){echo 'Sorry please try it again.';}else {echo 'Successfully sent.';}?>

Answer (score 0):

You probably need an AJAX request for that, if I understand you correctly.
You prevent the default action for the submit button, send the Ajax request and on success insert your success message ("Message sent") into the form div.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by two ways :

1) use your form like this `<form method="post" action="">`. Then in your php you have to catch the submit action, so you have to

```
if($_POST['submit'] == 'send') then write my html code into tooltip div
else show contact form
```

This method needs a reload of the page when the user click on submit button, i would encourage you using the second method.

2) Use AJAX to send your contact form, on submit you can execute javascript code..